# asp.net selectbox gives null on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I am trying to create a user identifier and used a selectbox so they can choose between identifier methods. I did fine one other question here that addressed the situation, but after following that example it still posted back null. 
It does show the selectbox correctly aswell as the containing data, however when i push save (post) the selected attr is not added and remains null.

code:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Authtype", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Authtype) 


@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Authtype, ViewBag.AvailableAuthorizationTypes as SelectList, "--- Select Category ---", new { @class = "some_class" })
```

both work (and yes show me the same result, I posted both in the hope that one might bring me further on the right track).

```
CreateIdentifierModel cim = new CreateIdentifierModel();
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> items = cim.AvailableAuthorizationTypes = Context.AuthorizationTypes.OrderBy(x => x.Name)
            .Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Identifier.ToString() });
        ViewBag.Authtype = items;
        return View();
```

When i click save it will go to the post method, but keeps the attr null, eventhough one of the options is selected. 
It is probably a brain fart but I can't seem to work out where exactly the problem is and how to fix it. CAn someone help me out?

Kind regards,

Comment: I edit my answer you could try it and if it right please check it as the solution :)

Comment: _it will go to the post method, but keeps the attr null_ - What POST method? We cannot guess what mistakes you have made. Show the relevant code (the controller methods and your model)

Comment: Turned out that the error was with the database and it giving back a null on request on authtypes. Considering im new to the system and aps.net I kept on thinking the problem was in my code. Ahwell at least it is fixed now. Thanks for the provided answers and different ways to fix it though!

Comment: Please delete your question - its of not use to anyone else.